# Text box shows values incorrectly after return to page (ASP.NET 3.5)

Tags: asp.net

could you please clarify my issue?

I have a starting page ListBox1.aspx that calls another one ListBox1_sub.aspx. I need to preserve a state of the page ListBox1.aspx so that after returning from ListBox1_sub.aspx all the controls of ListBox1.aspx keep their state. I assume it could be achieved by using a client-side code and in the attached code everything looks OK except one thing.

In my code, I set the value of the Session variable Session("back_from_ListBox1_sub") in ListBox1_sub.aspx. After returning from ListBox1_sub.aspx to ListBox1.aspx, I expected the txtReturn TextBox to show the value of the Session variable. However, although this value was set to the text box, it was not shown.

In the below code, the value of the Session variable is displayed only after the 2nd call to ListBox1_sub.aspx. For example, if I set the value to "x" in the first call and to "y" in the second call, after returning from the 2d call the value will be set to "x".

Can you advise as to how I should modify my code so that the returned value be displayed correctly in the first page after the call to the second page?
Many Thanks,
Lev

======= test code =======
== ListBox1.aspx =====

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ListBox1.aspx.vb" Inherits="ListBox1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat=server Visible="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="a" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="b" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="c" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="d" />
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
     <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkWindowOpen" runat="server" Text="Window.Open">
    </asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtReturn" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

'code-behind

```
Partial Class ListBox1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Const JS_START As String = "<script language=javascript>"
    Public Const JS_END As String = "</script>"
    Public Const DBQT As Char = Chr(34)

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not (Session("back_from_ListBox1_sub") Is Nothing) Then
            txtReturn.Text = Session("back_from_ListBox1_sub").ToString
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Sub lnkWindowOpen_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkWindowOpen.Click
        Dim message As String
        Dim script As String
        message = ""
        message += "window.blur();"
        message += "window.open(" & DBQT & "ListBox1_sub.aspx" & DBQT & ",null,"
        message += DBQT & "height=200,width=400,top=300,left=325,"
        message += "status=yes,toolbar=no,titlebar=0,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=0,resizable=0;modal=yes" & DBQT & ");"
        script = JS_START & message & JS_END
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script)
    End Sub

End Class
```

======== page ListBox1_sub.aspx ==========

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ListBox1_sub.aspx.vb" Inherits="ListBox1_sub" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="x" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="y" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="z" />
    </asp:ListBox>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBack" runat="server">Back</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

'code-behind

```
Partial Class ListBox1_sub
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Const JS_START As String = "<script language=javascript>"
    Public Const JS_END As String = "</script>"
    Public Const DBQT As Char = Chr(34)

    Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text
    End Sub

    Protected Sub lnkBack_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkBack.Click
        Dim message As String
        Dim script As String
        Session("back_from_ListBox1_sub") = TextBox1.Text
        message = "window.close();"
        script = JS_START & message & JS_END
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your value isn't showing is because the page that opens the pop-up isn't refreshing to show the new value.

In your lnkBack_Click try setting message to this.

```
message = "window.close();"
message += "if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {"
message += "    window.opener.location.reload();"
message += "}"
```

This will close the pop-up and tell the first page to reload.

EDIT: Update the field with javascript instead of re-loading

What we will do is pass the id of the field we want to update to the popup. When the user clicks the button we find the field on the opening page and update it. We no longer need to use session to pass the values. I am not at a PC where I can test the code, so it might not work as is. I don't do any error checking, you will want to add this.

Partial Class ListBox1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Public Const JS_START As String = "<script language=javascript>"
Public Const JS_END As String = "</script>"
Public Const DBQT As Char = Chr(34)

Protected Sub lnkWindowOpen_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkWindowOpen.Click
    Dim message As String
    Dim script As String
    message = ""
    message += "window.blur();"
    message += "window.open(" & DBQT & "ListBox1_sub.aspx?ctrl=" & txtReturn.ClientId & DBQT & ",null,"
    message += DBQT & "height=200,width=400,top=300,left=325,"
    message += "status=yes,toolbar=no,titlebar=0,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=0,resizable=0;modal=yes" & DBQT & ");"
    script = JS_START & message & JS_END
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script)
End Sub
```

End Class

Partial Class ListBox1_sub
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Public Const JS_START As String = "<script language=javascript>"
Public Const JS_END As String = "</script>"
Public Const DBQT As Char = Chr(34)

Protected Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    TextBox1.Text = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text
End Sub

Protected Sub lnkBack_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lnkBack.Click
    Dim message As String
    Dim script As String
    message = "window.close();"
    message += "var ctrl = window.opener.document.getElementById('" & Request.QueryString("ctrl") & "');"
    message += "ctrl.value = '" & TextBox1.Text.Replace("'", "\'") & "';";
    script = JS_START & message & JS_END
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), script)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Mike, Thanks. But now after I click Back on the 2d page, the dialog appears that says that IE needs to resend the submitted info again. If I click either the Retry or Cancel button, the 2d page pops up again so I need to close it explicitly. How to avoid appearing the dialog and closing the second page?

Comment: Instead of window.opener.location.reload() you could do window.opener.location = window.opener.location;

Comment: Mike, Thanks. I've tried your suggestion. The good news is that I'm redirected to the first page but the bad news that I lose the values of the controls on the first page, i.e. they are reset. Is it possible to modify the code so that the state of the first page be preserved? The current code in the 2d page is:
message += "window.close();"
message += "if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) {"
message += "    window.opener.location = window.opener.location;"
message += "}"
Lev

Comment: Lev, I've edited my answer w/ an alternative solution. Let me know if you have any questions.